# Mongodb Meteor 2 Collection Query Aggregation Maximum Call Stack Exceed

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have 2 collections.One is Resources other is Items

Resources:

```
{
    "_id" : "fGR4ECcw5p2HFgxd3",
    "ownerId" : "J8MpsWChPQdET6jwQ",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-04T07:25:28.418Z"),
    "inventory" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b537ef5895adfeae037e0a4"),
            "quantity" : 10
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b537d9c895adfeae037dbd2"),
            "quantity" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

There are 2 documents in Items Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b537d9c895adfeae037dbd2"),
    "name" : "Item1",
    "useable" : true,
    "img" : ""
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b537ef5895adfeae037e0a4"),
    "name" : "Item2",
    "useable" : false,
    "img" : ""
}
```

As you see there are ids of items in inventory array.

What i am trying to do is how do i write a correct query to get an inventory array with each items information(coming from items collection)

Example:

```
    "inventory" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b537ef5895adfeae037e0a4"),
                "name":"Item2",
                "useable":false,
                "img":"",
                "quantity" : 10
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b537d9c895adfeae037dbd2"),
                "name":"Item1",
                "useable":true,
                "img":"",
                "quantity" : 5
            }
]
```

I am using meteor hacks aggregation package:
Tried Anthony Winzlets answer
This is server side method:

```
'getInventory':function(userid){
    return Resources.aggregate([
      { "$match": { "ownerId": userid } },
      { "$unwind": "$inventory" },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Items,
        "let": { "inventoryId": "$inventory._id", "quantity": "$quantity" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$inventoryId" ] } } },
          { "$addFields": { "quantity": "$$quantity" } }
        ],
        "as": "inventory"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$inventory" },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "ownerId": { "$first": "$ownerId" },
        "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
        "inventory": { "$push": "$inventory" }
      }}
    ])
  }
```

with Items.collecion.name  i get undefined
with Items.name  same error as just Items(call stack size exceed)
This is the error i get :

```
W20180721-23:18:22.253(3)? (STDERR) (node:10800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
W20180721-23:18:22.254(3)? (STDERR)     at Array.some (<anonymous>)
W20180721-23:18:22.254(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.matchObject (packages/ejson/ejson.js:180:31)
W20180721-23:18:22.254(3)? (STDERR)     at toJSONValueHelper (packages/ejson/ejson.js:239:19)
W20180721-23:18:22.254(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.toJSONValue.item [as toJSONValue] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:292:19)
W20180721-23:18:22.255(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:188:29)
W20180721-23:18:22.255(3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180721-23:18:22.255(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.toJSONValue (packages/ejson/ejson.js:187:24)
W20180721-23:18:22.256(3)? (STDERR)     at toJSONValueHelper (packages/ejson/ejson.js:240:24)
W20180721-23:18:22.256(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.toJSONValue.item [as toJSONValue] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:292:19)
W20180721-23:18:22.257(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:188:29)
W20180721-23:18:22.257(3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180721-23:18:22.258(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.toJSONValue (packages/ejson/ejson.js:187:24)
W20180721-23:18:22.258(3)? (STDERR)     at toJSONValueHelper (packages/ejson/ejson.js:240:24)
W20180721-23:18:22.259(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.EJSON.toJSONValue.item [as toJSONValue] (packages/ejson/ejson.js:292:19)
W20180721-23:18:22.259(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.keys.forEach.key (packages/ejson/ejson.js:188:29)
W20180721-23:18:22.259(3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180721-23:18:22.260(3)? (STDERR) (node:10800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
W20180721-23:18:22.261(3)? (STDERR) (node:10800) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below  [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation

```
db.resources.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "ownerId": Meteor.userId() } },
  { "$unwind": "$inventory" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Items.collection.name,
    "let": { "inventoryId": "$inventory._id", "quantity": "$quantity" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$inventoryId" ] } } },
      { "$addFields": { "quantity": "$$quantity" } }
    ],
    "as": "inventory"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$inventory" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "ownerId": { "$first": "$ownerId" },
    "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
    "inventory": { "$push": "$inventory" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Items is your collection name... Import it just like you have imported the resources model

Comment: I couldnt really understand what this query is doing.For example i need to send users id to server for query (ownerId) with using Meteor.userid()    where is it used  ?

Comment: Ok I added that condition... This query will join your both the collections with `$lookup` aggregation and will give you the output as you posted in the question

Comment: "from": Items.collection.name,      this is undefined with Items imported if i try Items.name i get this error : (node:15620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Please don't update the question if you have new issue then please ask a new question... Btw what is your mongodb version?

Comment: my mongodb version is 3.6.4

Comment: Then it should work ... Put a `$limit` after match condition

Comment: can you post your full code in the question where you used aggregate query